# Android - How to display place details like in google map app when click on marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

Is there any way to programmatically display place details like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac0Pv.jpg) (like in google map app) when click on marker or I have to create my own layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would probably have to design the inner HTMl yourself but it is doable.

When you click on a map you want to open an info window with the HTML rendered inside.

The question is rather broad so I am unsure how much detail is required. I suggest editing the question to be more specific:

Here is a JSfiddle showing a simple info marker with some HTMl sat inside decalred as the `contentstring`: https://jsfiddle.net/j1j6m50t/